# Deriving from Binding class (Silverlight 4.0)

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, binding, markup-extensions

Using the existing `Binding` class, we can write,

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Email, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

So we can write *anything* as Email; there is no validity check by `Binding` itself. I started writing a class `BindingMore` deriving from `Binding` so that eventually I could write,

```
 <TextBox Text="{local:BindingMore Email, Validate=SomeMethod, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Where `SomeMethod` is some `ICommand` or `delegate` which will be triggered to validate the `Email` .  That is my objective, and I've not written that yet.

As of now, I've written just this code,

```
public class BindingMore : System.Windows.Data.Binding
{
    public BindingMore() : base() 
    { 
    }
    public BindingMore(string path) : base(path)
    {
    }
}
```

So, at this stage, `BindingMore` is exactly equivalent to `Binding`, yet when I write

```
 <TextBox Text="{local:BindingMore Email, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

It's giving me runtime error. But when I write,

```
 <TextBox Text="{local:BindingMore Path=Email, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

It's working fine. Can anybody tell me why it's giving runtime error in the first case?

Unfortunately, the error is not shown. All it shows is this:
[image]

Also, I get the following error message from XAML (even when it builds perfectly and runs (in the second case)):

> Type 'local:BindingMore' is used like
>   a markup extension but does not derive
>   from MarkupExtension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom `Markup Extensions` are not supported in `Silverlight`. Try using an `Attached Property` approach or a `Behavior`.

Comment: Behavior? What is this? Some class? Can you please give me some links?

Comment: http://wildermuth.com/2009/05/16/Writing_Behaviors_for_Silverlight_3_-_Part_1 and http://wildermuth.com/2009/05/16/Writing_Behaviors_for_Silverlight_3_-_Part_2

Comment: Just search for `Silverlight Behaviors` and you will get a lot of examples on web.

Comment: On the upside, markup extensions are coming in Silverlight 5, as announced at the Silverlight Firestarter.